# Counting visible elements in a layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

Suppose in my `LinearLayout` (say parentLayout) there are 5 other `LinearLayouts` (say childLayout), where only one of them are visible at the moment. The other layouts depend on some external event to make them visible. How do I count the number of childLayout in the parentLayout that are visible ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can iterate over the children of the parent layout and check their visibility.  Something like this:

```
LinearLaout parent = ...;
int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
    if(parent.getChildAt(i).getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        count++;
    }
}
System.out.println("Visible children: " + count);
```

Answer (score 2):

here is a funntion that returns number of visible childs in ViewGroup like LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, ScrollView, ..etc

```
private int countVisible(ViewGroup myLayout)
{
    if(myLayout==null) return 0;
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<myLayout.getChildCount();i++)
    {
        if(myLayout.getChildAt(i).getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Kotlin just use extention:

```
fun LinearLayout.visibleChildCount(): Int {
  var childVisible = 0
  children.iterator().forEach {
      if(it.isVisible) ++childVisible
  }
  return childVisible
}
```